# Vapor: Saving Byte array to SQLite database?

Tags: swift, sqlite, vapor

I’m having trouble saving a large (~20k) JSON blob into an SQLite database. I created the row with `builder.bytes("data")`, which turned into a `blob`row in the database file. When I try saving an array of Byte aka Bytes, I get this error:

`S Q Lite Driver Error: Unsupported Command: Array values not supported.] [Identifier: Fluent.SQLiteDriverError.unsupported] [Possible Causes: using operations not supported by sqlite] [Suggested Fixes: verify data is not corrupt if data type should be supported by sqlite]`

The error message comes from the switch statement implemented [here](https://github.com/vapor-community/sqlite-driver/blob/master/Sources/FluentSQLite/SQLiteDriver.swift#L91).

There’s a separate `bytes` case defined in the `StructuredData` enum, which seems to be supported by the SQLDriver, but I don’t know how to get there.

This is how my class is defined:

final class Blob: Model {
   let storage = Storage()

```
let uuid: String
let revision: Int
let userId: Identifier
let data: Bytes


init(uuid inUuid: String, revision inRevision: Int, data inData: [UInt8], user: User) throws {
    uuid = inUuid
    userId = try user.assertExists()
    revision = inRevision
    data = inData
}

init(row: Row) throws {
    uuid = try row.get("uuid")
    userId = try row.get(User.foreignIdKey)
    revision = try row.get("revision")
    data = try row.get("data")
}

func makeRow() throws -> Row {
    var row = Row()
    try row.set("uuid", uuid)
    try row.set(User.foreignIdKey, userId)
    try row.set("revision", revision)
    try row.set("data", data)
    return row
}
```

}

This is using Vapor Toolbox 2.0.3 and Vapor Framework 2.1.3.

Comment: Can you please include how you implemented `makeRow()` and `init(row:)` as well? Especially how you set/get the data property.

Comment: Updated my original post with more code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the current versions of Vapor 2, you cannot rely on the Fuzzy `get`/`set` methods when converting byte arrays from/to Nodes and other StructuredDataWrappers.

Instead, you have to make both directions explicit:

```
init(row: Row) throws {
    // ...
    data = row["data"]?.bytes ?? []
}

func makeRow() throws -> Row {
    var row = Row()
    // ...
    try row.set("data", StructuredData.bytes(data))
    return row
}
```

---

[Here](https://github.com/vapor/node/issues/86) is the related issue on GitHub.